# Problema al hacer una funcion click en un boton con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

La idea es que al apretar el boton de volver que se genera a partir de la funcion de jQuery, se coloquen en el main los elementos que estaban anteriormente.

El problema es que al hacer click, no se me realiza ni el console log ni aparecen los demas elementos guardados en la variable div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div = "";

  $('#cardPrimero').click(function() {
    div = $('#divBusqueda').detach();
    $('main').html('<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="botonVolver">Volver</button>');
  });

  $('#botonVolver').click(function() {
    console.log('hola');
    $('main').html(div);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="container col-md-6 text-center" id="divBusqueda">

    <!--Parte de Busqueda-->
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Te damos la bienvenida al soporte de la Universidad de Belgrano</h1>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Cards de Ayuda-->
    <div class="container row d-flex justify-content-between" id="divBusqueda">
      <div class="card col-md-3 cardAyuda" id="cardPrimero">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/40/000000/contacts-filled.png">
          <h3 class="text-justify textoCard">Contacto</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-3 cardAyuda">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/40/000000/contacts-filled.png">
          <h3 class="text-justify textoCard">Contacto</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-3 cardAyuda">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/40/000000/contacts-filled.png">
          <h3 class="text-justify textoCard">Contacto</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card col-md-3 cardAyuda">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/40/000000/contacts-filled.png">
          <h3 class="text-justify textoCard">Contacto</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: dentro de tu html no encuentro ningun boton volver... tampoco ninguno que contenga el id "botonVolver"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando defines el evento `$('#botonVolver').click(...)`, no existe ningún elemento en el DOM con esa id, porque es insertado dinámicamente después.

Deberías definir el evento de la siguiente manera:

```
$('main').on('click', '#botonVolver', function() {
    console.log('hola');
    $('main').html(div);
})
```

De esta manera cada vez que cliques dentro del tag `<main>`, jQuery comprobará si el click ha sido efectuado sobre un elemento con esa id, y en caso afirmativo, ejecturá la función.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque debes crear el evento click luego de añadir el botón cómo lo tienes ahora el evento se crea al cargar la página y el botón cuando haces click, osea después, el código correcto sería:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = "";

   $('#cardPrimero').click(function() {
       div = $('#divBusqueda').detach();
      $('main').html('<button class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="botonVolver">Volver</button>');

      $('#botonVolver').click(function() {
         console.log('hola');
        $('main').html(div);
      });
 });
```